# Parabola Equation from its trajectory points in a Video

Tags: conic-sections, computer-vision

I have a video of an object describing a ballistic trajectory (i.e. A ball being thrown) 
The video is filmed with an angle and not orthogonally to the moving object, the camera is calibrated.

I am able to register the ball centres along the frames and extract the trajectory points.

Knowing all points and that the trajectory is a parabola, is there a way to recover the parabola plane and its equation?

Comment: Im not sure if i understand the problem completely but if you know at least 3 (x, y) coordinates of the parabola you can make a system of equations and solve.

Comment: Suppose i have domenica of the points in the trajectory in the Image.
The Red trajectory is a parabola in real world, but since the Image is taken from an angle, It is not a parabola in the Image.

From these Image coordinates, i want to extract the parabola equation.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVzBt.png)

Comment: Interesting problem. As you note, the trajectory in the image will not generally be a parabola—it will be hyperbolic unless the trajectory is parallel to the image plane. I suspect that you’ll have to use other cues in the scene, such as apparent ball size, to determine the trajectory plane uniquely. One you have that, back-mapping the data points to this plane is simple, and then you should be able to fit a parabola to the transformed points.